# Is it possible to show/open a View by using Javascript in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an Action Method which returns the View i want to show.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LoginSuccess(string data)
        {
         
                return View(); 
            
        }
```

This Action Method is called by a JQuery Post Method. The POST Method sends the values of the two Textboxes, sepeterated by dashes, to the ActionMethod. This works as expected.

```
<form class='login-form'>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <input id="username" class='lf--input' placeholder='Username' type='text'>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <input id="password" class='inpPW' placeholder='Password' type='password'>
    </div>
    <input class='lf--submit' type='submit' onclick="sendData()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendData() {

        var txtUsername = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var txtPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var fullString = [txtUsername, txtPassword].join('-');
        $.post('/Login/LoginSuccess', { "data": fullString });
    }
</script>
```

However, when I try click the submit Button, the Action Method is called as expected, but it is not redirecting me to the expected view. Instead, it just adds an Question Mark to the URL and reloads the Site.

I already know its possible just by adding "action="/Login/LoginSuccess" method="post"" to the Forms Tag, but is there a way to use Javascript for this action?

Comment: do u mean u wanna redirect after the user has succesfully login? If so, you can do it under your  login succrss controller by add return RedirectToAction("YourAction","YoutController");

Comment: already tried that, didnt work unfortunately. I think that something is wrong with the JQuery POST function, i just cant figure out what exactly.

Comment: The javascript statement `$.post()` is an AJAX call.  Usually an AJAX call is used to avoid a full page postback, preferring to instead call the server asynchronously and then update the HTML of the *current* page.  Your scenario seems to want to render a full view after the post call.   It can be done via AJAX but I seriously wonder if the extra complexity is worth it to you, if I understand your scenario correctly.